# Is there a way to identify columns in dataframe where decimal places have shifted?

Tags: r

Let's say I've got a dataframe like this:

```
Sample1  Sample2  Sample3  Sample4
0.2      0.4      0.02     0.04
0.3      1        0.03     0.002
0.5      0.6      0.05     0.1
```

`Sample1` and `Sample3` have the same values, but in `Sample3` the decimal place has shifted from 0.2 to 0.02 and so on. This can be a result of an import error in what I'm doing.

How could I detect such cases?

Comment: You probably haven't supplied enough information for anyone to give you a definitive answer here. How do you know, when you look at the data, that one of the columns has the wrong number of decimal places? What "rules" are you using when you see the data that tell you it is wrong? It is these same rules that we would need to code a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
# create example data
df <-
  data.frame(
    x1 = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5),
    x2 = c(.1, .2, .3),
    x3 = c(0.02, .03, .05),
    x4 = c(6, 7, 8),
    x5 = c(1, 2, 3),
    x6 = c(.001, .002, .003)
  )
myNrows <- nrow(df)

# amount of decimals you want to check
ShiftCheck <- 3

# actual solution
for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
  comparecols <- colnames(df)[-j]
  for (mycol in comparecols) {
    if (max(colSums(df[, j] == df[, mycol] %*% t(10 ^ c(1:ShiftCheck)))) == myNrows) {
      shifting <-
        which.max(colSums(df[, j] == df[, mycol] %*% t(10 ^ c(1:3))))
      print(
        paste0(
          colnames(df)[j],
          ' and ',
          mycol,
          ' are the same besides being shifted ',
          shifting,
          ' decimal place(s)'
        )
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What if decimals have been shifted two or more places?

Comment: Code adapted to check for more decimal places

Comment: Steffen, as long as user is assured to have knowledge of the number of decimal places some column may have shifted, your earlier code (with a bit modification) could have worked! Out of just my curiosity, I wanted a code which could check for such shift without having a knowledge of it already.  So a good code will be which can check all possibilities here.  I think the strategy should be to divide each pair of columns (in all permutations/combinations) and to check that all values in that resultant vector are same.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! This works! Is there a way to make this work for a df that contains NA's? When I try, it throws me an error that `Error in if (max(colSums(df[, j] == df[, mycol] %*% t(10^c(1:ShiftCheck)))) ==  :missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`